# Localhost SSL connection to api ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

I'm trying to connect to an API via Chrome in my dev environment.

I have configured the localhost to run under SSL for testing,

When I connect to the API with `https://` I get this error

> ```
> request.js:132 OPTIONS https://api.thenounproject.com:80/icons/test
> net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
> ```

To get the local dev running on https in Chrome I've had to enable :

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost.
```

Is there anyway around these pesky security issues in development environment?

Comment: 1) Are you sure you're running HTTPS on port 80 and not 443? 2) That's not localhost, you must have entered the wrong URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Old question, and probably you already have an answer, but I'll post it anyway as it is the top hit on google if you look for `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` and `localhost` (with 732 views).

I had this error with `NGINX` and got `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in google chrome. Googling that error message didn't give me a quick answer. Firefox however throws `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`. Googling that error message led me to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/497430/error-code-ssl-error-rx-record-too-long) on Server Fault and its accepted answer worked for me.

All I had to do was add `ssl` to the listen line in the server block:

```
listen 443 ssl;
```

[`NGINX` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) also mentions that.

> To configure an HTTPS server, the ssl parameter must be enabled on
>   listening sockets in the server block, and the locations of the server
>   certificate and private key files should be specified:

Comment: If you're using react-scripts in your package.json add "start": "HTTPS=TRUE react-scripts start"

Answer (score 0):

```
net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR at https://localhost:8086
at navigate (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/FrameManager.ts:190:13)
```

I have the same issue with VUE and Puppeteer. Fixing all certificates in OS will help (localhost API/APP/root CA + Chrome)